# how can i update multiple use php/ajax in datatable checkbox?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a datatable filled in by `SALARIES` with checkbox and button update_all and dropdownlist contains `CHANTIER_IDs`, I want to do multiple update of `CHANTIER_IDs` using php / ajax .`CHANTIER_IDs` of `SALARIES` cheked in datatable will be modified by value select in dropdownlist.
I want when I click on button update all the values of `chantire_ids` of cheked `SALARIES` will be modified by the value selected in dropdownlist

**affectation.php**

```
<div class="container" id="app">
    <h3>affecter salarie a chantier</h3>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3  ">
        <select class="form-control" id="chantier">
<?php
    include "../conn/connexion.php";
    $query = "SELECT id,chantier FROM chantier";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    for ($i=0; $i <$n ; $i++) { 
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" ><?php echo $row[1]; 
    } ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success update-all" data-url="">Update All</button>
    <button style="margin: 5px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-all" data-url="">Delete All</button>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>nom & prenom</th>
            <th>cin</th>
            <th>matricule</th>
            <th>chantier_ids</th>
        </tr>
<?php 
    $query1 = "SELECT id,nom,prenom,cin,matricule,chantier_id 
                FROM salaries";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$query1);
    $n1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
    for ($i=0; $i <$n1 ; $i++) { 
        $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
    ?>
        <tr id="tr_<?php $row[0] ?>">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="<?php $row[0] ?>"></td>
            <td><?php echo $row1[0]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row1[1]; ?>  <?php echo $row1[2]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row1[3]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row1[4]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row1[5]; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php 
    } 
?>
    </table>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
            if($(this).is(':checked',true)) {
                $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);  
            } else {  
                $(".checkbox").prop('checked',false);  
            }  
        });
        $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
            if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',true);
            }else{
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',false);
            }
        });
        $('.update-all').on('click', function(e) {
            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")){
                var id = [];
            } 
            $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
                id[i] = $(this).val();
            });
            if(id.length === 0) //tell you if the array is empty
            {
                alert("Please Select atleast one checkbox");
            }else{
                $.ajax({
                    url:'delete.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{id:id},
                    success:function(){
                        for(var i=0; i<id.length; i++){
                            $(this).parents("tr")
                                .children("td:last-child")
                                .text($('#app')
                                .children("option:selected")
                                .text());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**updateall.php**

```
<?php
include "conn/connexion";
if(isset($_POST["id"])) {
    foreach($_POST["id"] as $id) {
        $query = "UPDATE salaries 
                    SET chantier_id = ". $id ."  
                WHERE id = '".$id."'";
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you have terminated your for loop in the first `<option..` line

Comment: On this line `<option value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" ><?php echo $row[1]; 
    } ?></option>`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thx for answer but my SALARIES list display very will

Comment: THen this code may not be the real code you are running

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes because I am a beginner I am not how to solve this problem